# highlight a row when input value is changed by direct input or buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table row section on my site which includes a minus button,  an input field and an add button. I'm trying to make it so the background of the row highlights whenever the input is changed, either by directly typing into it or by increasing/decreasing with buttons.

The first issue is, my code isn't working. The page loads and the buttons increase/decrease the number in the input box correctly, but nothing highlights. So i need to get that to work but with one catch: I'd like the color to reset when '0' is back in the input box. So any number above zero would keep the highlight but '0' would return it to no highlight.

Here's the code so far:

```js
$("tr > td > input").focus(function(e) {
  $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlight');
}).blur(function(e) {
  $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('highlight');
});

$('.incrementer-class-name').each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
var $input = $this.find('.md-input');
$this.on('click', '.add-button', function() {
var val = parseInt($input.val());
$input.val(++val);
}).on('click', '.remove-button', function() {
var val = parseInt($input.val());
$input.val(--val);
});
});
```

```css
tr.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="incrementer-class-name">
        <button class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
        <input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $psku->quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0'
        />
        <button class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Updated with missing JS to show button function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery using the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function will help you highlight the row. Also jQuery has [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to help you with this as well.

First you need a event to listen to the change in the input (I used the keyup event) and then you check the value for the conditions you want and update the class of the closest `tr`.

This example is dynamic enough for you to add multiple rows and have it still work

```js
$('.incrementer-class-name').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $input = $this.find('.md-input');
  $this.on('click', '.add-button', function() {
    var val = parseInt($input.val());
    $input.val(++val);
    if (val === 0) {
      $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("highlight");
    } else {
      $(this).closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
    }
  }).on('click', '.remove-button', function() {
    var val = parseInt($input.val());
    $input.val(--val);
    if (val === 0) {
      $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("highlight");
    } else {
      $(this).closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
    }
  });
});

$(".highlightInput").on("keyup", function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() === "0") {
    $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("highlight");
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="incrementer-class-name">
        <button class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
        <input type="text" class="md-input highlightInput" id="{{ $psku->quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0'
        />
        <button class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yes, working perfectly! Thank you. Now will this be able to handle if something populates the box on page load, so if I go back to this page and the input is pre-loaded with existing quantities, will the row still highlight? Or only if it detects the change on the page?

Comment: no problem! depends on how its "pre-loaded" you might need to have code inside a `$( document ).ready(function() {//code here} });` block that does the same thing as above.

Answer (score 0):

add a `keyUp` event to your input

```
<input type="text" id="box" onkeyUp="doHighlight()" />
```

your css:

```
.highlight{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

create a function to highlight the textbox

```
function doHighlight(){
    var box = $('#box')
    var value = box.val();
    console.log(value);
    if(value === '0'){
        box.removeClass("highlight");
    }
    else{
        box.addClass("highlight");
    }
}
```

also your `remove` and `add` buttons should make a call to the `doHighlight` function

EDIT:
for generated Id's pass your id into the `doHighlight` function so you have

```
function doHighlight(id){
    var box = $('#'+id)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup`

```js
$(".md-input").keyup(function(e) {
  var $input = $(e.currentTarget);
  setStyle($input.val(), $input);

})

$('.incrementer-class-name').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $input = $this.find('.md-input');
  $this.on('click', '.add-button', function() {
    var val = parseInt($input.val());
    $input.val(++val);
    setStyle($input.val(), $input);
  }).on('click', '.remove-button', function() {
    var val = parseInt($input.val());
    $input.val(--val);
    setStyle($input.val(), $input);
  });
});

function setStyle(value, e) {
  if (value == '0') {
    e.removeClass('highlight');
  } else {
    e.addClass('highlight');
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="incrementer-class-name">
        <button class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
        <input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $psku->quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0' />
        <button class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```